# Change the location of the text and display it on the app bar while scrolling in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

today i was exploring some apps and i faced an amazing App bar in an Android app and just wanted to know if there is any way to implement it in flutter?
when user scrolls down and reaches the title , title text changes it's position and sticks  to app bar. same happens with the tab bar. also it has some animation if you look more carefully.
any solution would be appreciated. thx

[image]

(hope image above is clear enough)

making flutter appbar react to scroll and change its child widgets

Comment: Sounds like slivers - https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/scrolling/slivers